# Why doesn't Normal[] work on GeometricTransformation?

Tags: graphics, conversion, geometric-transform

I have a polygon on which I'm applying a `GeometricTransform` and I want to get the coordinates of the transformed polygon. `Graphics[g]` works and shows it nicely, but `Normal@g` doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
g = GeometricTransformation[
     Polygon[{
      {-0.36551249999999996`, -0.29021463333333336`}, 
      {-0.36509784999999995`, -0.2812481916666667`}, 
      {-0.3619309499999999`, -0.2645122083333334`}, 
      {-0.3592788999999999`, -0.25668636666666667`}, 
      {-0.3520880999999999`, -0.2419782333333334`}, 
      {-0.34271569999999996`, -0.22834049999999997`}, 
      {-0.3254433499999999`, -0.209398275`}, 
      {-0.3055169`, -0.19159769999999998`}, 
      {-0.26311249999999997`,-0.15638130000000006`}, 
      {-0.24333994999999997`, -0.13744537499999998`}, 
      {-0.22632409999999997`, -0.11661089999999996`}, 
      {-0.21717969999999998`, -0.10129116666666663`}, 
      {-0.21341764999999996`, -0.09311782500000006`}, 
      {-0.16110257499999997`, 0.0714712708333333`}, 
      {-0.1087875`, 0.23606036666666666`}, 
      {-0.3035939666666666`, -0.33778329166666676`}, 
      {-0.32013196666666666`, -0.3382103666666666`}, 
      {-0.33230609999999994`, -0.33689943333333333`}, 
      {-0.3425458333333333`, -0.3340813000000001`}, 
      {-0.3508735666666666`, -0.32955116666666673`}, 
      {-0.3558780916666666`, -0.3249068666666666`}, 
      {-0.36091372499999996`, -0.3168879333333333`}, 
      {-0.3634749`, -0.3093918333333333`}, 
      {-0.365004675`, -0.3005295333333334`}, 
      {-0.36551249999999996`, -0.29021463333333336`}}
     ], 
     {{-0.14929987960875826`, -1.065591641272026`}, 
      {1.0642599291951356`, -0.14911329363618442`}
     }
   ]
```

Comment: I do not believe [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normal.html) will give you the coordinates, but `Polygon[...][[1]]` will.

Comment: @rcollyer he means the *transformed* coordinates.  "When possible, `Normal` will perform the transformations explicitly:"

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ah, I see it now. And, I see his problem, too.

Comment: @rcollyer Ohhh... you meant it looks bad in mma. Yes, that I agree with — I was bitching about it a lot in chat when I first got my laptop (which is the chat discussion I linked to). Hopefully v9 supports retina. But then, if you had it in mma, you would've seen that it had a second argument because the little red triangle didn't pop up :)

Answer (score 17):

A bug report has been generated on this issue, but I don't believe any resources are being expended on it at the present time *(note that the more user reports are received on an issue, the more likely it is that the issue will get resources).* As a workaround, it is possible to hook into the internal code that is used for [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D) primitives. The key idea is that [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) knows how to convert 2D graphics primitives. Here are a couple examples:

```
TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[Pi/4, {.5, .5}]]
TransformedRegion[Line[{{0,0}, {1,1}, {1,2}}], ScalingTransform[{2,3}, {1,1}]]
```

> Parallelogram[{0.5, -0.207107}, {{-0.707107, 0.707107}, {0.707107, 0.707107}}]
>
> Line[{{-1, -2}, {1, 1}, {1, 4}}]

So, what is needed is a way to convert objects like `Rotate[Rectangle[], Pi/4]` into the equivalent [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation)/[`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) version. This is not as simple as it might seem because unless otherwise specified, [`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate) and [`Scale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale) keep some point of the body fixed. Hence the following two [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) outputs are different:

```
GraphicsRow[{
    Graphics[{Rotate[Rectangle[], Pi/4]}, Axes->True, PlotRange->{{-1,1.5}, {-.5, 1.5}}],
    Graphics[{TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[Pi/4]]}, Axes->True,PlotRange->{{-1,1.5}, {-.5, 1.5}}]
}]
```

[image]

The [`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate) object keeps the center of the rectangle fixed, while the [`RotationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform) keeps the origin fixed. One needs to determine the coordinate that [`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate)/[`Scale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale) fix, and then feed that to the appropriate transform. The default case is to use the center of the bounding rectangle, which can be determined with the following function:

```
regionCenter[g_] := Mean /@ RegionBounds[g]
```

For example:

```
regionCenter[Rectangle[]]
regionCenter[Triangle[]]
regionCenter[Circle[{0,0}, {1, 2}, {0, Pi}]]
```

> {1/2, 1/2}
>
> {1/2, 1/2}
>
> {0, 1}

Note that this is different from [`RegionCentroid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionCentroid)! The other case that must be handled is when symbolic position specifications like [`Left`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Left) and [`Bottom`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Bottom) are used. Here is a function that converts these symbolic based position specifications into actual coordinates:

```
absolutePosition[g_, {h:(Left|Center|Right), v:(Top|Center|Bottom)}] := Module[
    {hrange,vrange},

    {hrange, vrange} = RegionBounds[g][[;;2]];
    {
        Replace[h, {Left->Min, Center->Mean, Right->Max}][hrange],
        Replace[v, {Bottom->Min, Center->Mean, Top->Max}][vrange]
    }
]
absolutePosition[g_, spec_]:=spec
```

Note that the `regionCenter` function is just a special case where the second argument is `{Center, Center}`. Here is an example:

```
Graphics[Triangle[], Axes->True, ImageSize->100]
absolutePosition[Triangle[], {Right, Top}]
```

[image]

> {1, 1}

And yes, the fixed point of rotation with a position spec of `{Right, Top}` is indeed `{1, 1}`:

```
Graphics[
    {
        Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{1,1}],
        Green, Triangle[],
        Blue, Rotate[Triangle[], Pi/2, {Right, Top}]
    },
    Axes->True, PlotRange->{{0, 2}, {0, 1}}
]
```

[image]

Finally, [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation) evaluates to a form where the transform has been converted to the equivalent matrix version, but this form doesn't work in [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion):

```
GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], TranslationTransform[{1,1}]]
```

> GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[{0, 0}], {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {1, 1}}]

```
TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], {{{1,0},{0,1}},{1,1}}]
```

> TransformedRegion::vfunc: {{{1,0},{0,1}},{1,1}} evaluated at a list of length 2 should give a non-empty list.
>
> TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}], {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {1, 1}}]

One must convert the matrix representation back into a transform representation:

```
TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], AffineTransform[{{{1,0},{0,1}},{1,1}}]]
```

> Rectangle[{1, 1}, {2, 2}]

The internal code that I will hook into is `` System`Private`InternalNormal ``, which has a conditioned [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) to convert 3D graphics. When that [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) fails for 2D graphics, the new [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) that I add will be used. Here is the complete code:

```
NormalizeGraphics[g_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{System`Private`InternalNormal},
    Unprotect[System`Private`InternalNormal];
    System`Private`InternalNormal[
        gr:_Rotate|_Translate|_Scale|_GeometricTransformation,
        _
    ] := Module[{tmp = Quiet[transform2D[gr], TransformedRegion::reg]},
        tmp /; Head[tmp]=!=TransformedRegion
    ];
    Normal[g, {Rotate, Scale, Translate, GeometricTransformation}]
]

transform2D[Rotate[g_, r_, p___]] := TransformedRegion[
    g,
    RotationTransform[r, absolutePosition[g, p]]
]

transform2D[Translate[g_, t_]] := TransformedRegion[
    g,
    TranslationTransform[t]
]

transform2D[Scale[g_, s_, p___]] := TransformedRegion[
    g,
    ScalingTransform[s, absolutePosition[g, p]]
]

transform2D[GeometricTransformation[g_, tf_]] := TransformedRegion[
    g,
    tf /. Except[_TransformationRegion] :> AffineTransform[tf]
]

absolutePosition[g_] := absolutePosition[g, {Center, Center}]
absolutePosition[g_, {h:(Left|Center|Right), v:(Top|Center|Bottom)}] := Module[
    {hrange,vrange},

    {hrange, vrange} = RegionBounds[g][[;;2]];
    {
        Replace[h, {Left->Min, Center->Mean,Right->Max}][hrange],
        Replace[v,{Bottom->Min,Center->Mean,Top->Max}][vrange]
    }
]
absolutePosition[g_, spec_]:=spec
```

And here is an example of `NormalizeGraphics` in action:

```
g = Graphics[{
    GeometricTransformation[Circle[], TranslationTransform[{-1,1}]],
    Rotate[Rectangle[], Pi/4],
    Scale[Triangle[], {1,2}]
}]
```

[image]

```
normal = NormalizeGraphics @ g
normal //InputForm
```

[image]

> Graphics[{Circle[{-1, 1}, 1], Polygon[{{1/2, (1 - Sqrt[2])/2}, 
>       {1/2 - 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2] + (1 - Sqrt[2])/2}, {1/2, Sqrt[2] + (1 - Sqrt[2])/2}, 
>       {1/2 + 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2] + (1 - Sqrt[2])/2}}], Triangle[{{0, -1/2}, {1, -1/2}, {0, 3/2}}]}]

Note the absence of [`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate), [`Scale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale) and [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation)!

Finally, the example from the OP:

```
NormalizeGraphics @ Graphics[g]
% //InputForm
```

[image]

> Graphics[Polygon[{{0.3638212597003222, -0.34572544753218604}, {0.35420478721328924, 
>      -0.34662116780165864}, {0.3358982454760883, -0.34574632062896415}, {0.3271631432644535, 
>      -0.34409078711013413}, {0.3104166937514485, -0.3386310850158512}, {0.2944851409139063, 
>      -0.3306899825905281}, {0.27172170451125205, -0.3151322501610421}, {0.2497785439953863, 
>      -0.29657963026179973}, {0.20592127070481253, -0.25670155991424687}, {0.18279126797050033, 
>      -0.23848202539603736}, {0.15804976120376862, -0.22347943526827302}, {0.14035992359815785, 
>      -0.2160317926667024}, {0.13108880542481546, -0.21324674749600434}, {-0.05210659373892817, 
>      -0.18211233165697607}, {-0.2353019929026718, -0.15097791581794784}, {0.4052655948346296, 
>      -0.2727349143130483}, {0.4081898037937953, -0.29027196246219794}, {0.40861048083253815, 
>      -0.3034238823286141}, {0.40713629246244065, -0.31474184134416383}, {0.40355234983267335, 
>      -0.3242802173337974}, {0.39935059755311264, -0.3302988596255873}, {0.39155750867161554, 
>      -0.3368538119611556}, {0.38395211028863324, -0.3406973360457382}, {0.3747369127095167, 
>      -0.3436469010211146}, {0.3638212597003222, -0.34572544753218604}}]]

Comment: This is really nifty. Thank you for posting it!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why `Normal` does not work, but you can perform at least the transformation shown like this:

```
pts = {{-0.36551249999999996`, -0.29021463333333336`}, \
{-0.36509784999999995`, -0.2812481916666667`}, {-0.3619309499999999`, \
-0.2645122083333334`}, {-0.3592788999999999`, -0.25668636666666667`}, \
{-0.3520880999999999`, -0.2419782333333334`}, {-0.34271569999999996`, \
-0.22834049999999997`}, {-0.3254433499999999`, -0.209398275`}, \
{-0.3055169`, -0.19159769999999998`}, {-0.26311249999999997`, \
-0.15638130000000006`}, {-0.24333994999999997`, \
-0.13744537499999998`}, {-0.22632409999999997`, \
-0.11661089999999996`}, {-0.21717969999999998`, \
-0.10129116666666663`}, {-0.21341764999999996`, \
-0.09311782500000006`}, {-0.16110257499999997`, 
    0.0714712708333333`}, {-0.1087875`, 
    0.23606036666666666`}, {-0.3035939666666666`, \
-0.33778329166666676`}, {-0.32013196666666666`, \
-0.3382103666666666`}, {-0.33230609999999994`, \
-0.33689943333333333`}, {-0.3425458333333333`, -0.3340813000000001`}, \
{-0.3508735666666666`, -0.32955116666666673`}, {-0.3558780916666666`, \
-0.3249068666666666`}, {-0.36091372499999996`, -0.3168879333333333`}, \
{-0.3634749`, -0.3093918333333333`}, {-0.365004675`, \
-0.3005295333333334`}, {-0.36551249999999996`, -0.29021463333333336`}};

tf = AffineTransform[{{-0.14929987960875826`, -1.065591641272026`}, \
{1.0642599291951356`, -0.14911329363618442`}}];

Graphics@Polygon[tf /@ pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]