# How to get explicit result of geometric transformation?

Tags: graphics, regions, geometry, geometric-transform

Seems like this simply rectangle rescale should work and return the exact coordinates of the transformed resulting rectangle (which should be `Rectangle[{0.25, 0.25}, {0.75, 0.75}]`):

```
Normal@GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
  ScalingTransform[{.5, .5}, {.5, .5}]]
```

Now, this roundabout works:

```
TransformedRegion[DiscretizeGraphics@Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]], 
  ScalingTransform[{.5, .5}, {.5, .5}]] // BoundingRegion

(*returns Cuboid[{0.25, 0.25}, {0.75, 0.75}]*)
```

but weirdly this doesn't:

```
DiscretizeGraphics@Graphics[{GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
    ScalingTransform[{.5, .5}, {.5, .5}]]}]
(* returns EmptyRegion[2]*)
```

Comment: Why not use `TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], ScalingTransform[{.5, .5}, {.5, .5}]]` instead?

Comment: @CarlWoll Good point, I think I tried that and it may work but I'd like the result to be a Rectangle object, and I'd also like to understand why this other usage fails.

Comment: Then your question is probably a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11430/45431.

Comment: OK thanks, but it doesn't look like there was a simple solution to that one

Comment: You could use the function `NormalizeGraphics` from my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153871/45431) to that question instead of `Normal`, although it still returns a `Parallelogram` object instead of a `Rectangle` object.