# Evaluation of Graphics3D transforms

Tags: graphics

I want to find the centroid of a graphics primitive after a series of rotation and translation transforms. But it seems that graphics transforms don't "evaluate". For example,
`FullForm[Graphics3D[Translate[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], {1, 0, 0}]]]` returns unevaluated. So
`DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[Translate[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], {1, 0, 0}]]]` command does not work. I also tried `DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}],TranslationTransform[{1, 0, 0}]]]]`, it also doesn't work. Is there a geometric transform function that explicitly transforms the coordinates of the graphics objects?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Why doesn't Normal\[\] work on GeometricTransformation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11430/why-doesnt-normal-work-on-geometrictransformation)

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to miss, but in the documentation for [`GeometricTransformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) it says

> `Normal[expr]` if possible replaces all `GeometricTransformation[Subscript[g, i],\[Ellipsis]]` constructs by versions of the `Subscript[g, i]` in which the coordinates have explicitly been transformed.

so in this case you have

```
In[360]:= Normal@
 GeometricTransformation[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], 
  TranslationTransform[{1, 0, 0}]]

Out[360]= Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1]
```

Note it isn't too difficult to find `GeometricTransformation` expressions that do not convert via [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html), so I guess that "if possible" comes into play there.

Comment: That works for translation, but already for rotation of a cube it doesn't seem to. `FullForm[Normal[
  Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 
    RotationMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}]]]]]`

Comment: @MikeR - use `RotationTransform` instead of `RotationMatrix`, but it still fails.  What seems to work in that case is `TransformedRegion[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 
 RotationTransform[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}]]`

Comment: Yes, that works! Also works for several sequential transforms, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: `TransformedRegion` is better for me than `GeometricTransformation`, but unfortunately the following code inexplicably doesn't do anything: `TransformedRegion[
 Parallelepiped[{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {{-1., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.0}, {0., 0., 1.}}], RotationTransform[0, {1, 1, 1}]]`. Any idea why?

Comment: @LiamBaker your `Parallelepiped` has two identical vectors, is that valid?  It works in `Graphics3D` but all region functionality rejects it.

Comment: @JasonB. ah, that explains why it wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use my [NormalizeGraphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153871/45431) function for this:

```
NormalizeGraphics @ Graphics3D[Translate[Sphere[{0,0,0}],{1,0,0}]] //InputForm
```

> Graphics3D[Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1]]