# Obtain coordinates from GeometricTransformation

Tags: geometric-transform

What is the best way to obtain the transformed polygon coordinates?  In the example below `g3` still contains `GeometricTransformation[Polygon[...]...` etc. — not the transformed coordinates.

```
g1 = Graphics[{Green, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3]}, {2, 1}, {0, 0}}]}];
g2 = g1 /. {Polygon[x_] :> GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x],
      RotationTransform[-30 Degree, {0, 0}]], Green -> LightBlue};
g3 = Graphics[First /@ {g1, g2}]
```

[image]

```
g3 // InputForm
```

> Graphics[{{RGBColor[0, 1, 0], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHBY.png)}, {2, 1}, {0, 0}}]},
> {RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1], GeometricTransformation[
> Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHBY.png)}, {2, 1}, {0, 0}}],
> {{{Sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHBY.png)/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHBY.png)/2}}, {0, 0}}]}}]

***Edit***

Carl Woll's 2017 solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153871/363) works, but can this be done with built-in functionality?

```
NormalizeGraphics@g3 // InputForm
```

> Graphics[{{RGBColor[0, 1, 0], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHBY.png)}, {2, 1}, {0, 0}}]},
> {RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHBY.png)/2}, {Sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHBY.png), 1},
> {1/2 + Sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHBY.png), -1 + Sqrt[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHBY.png)/2}}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]}}]

Actually it does not work in this case:

```
g1 = Graphics[{Green,
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3]}, {2, 1}, {0, 0}}]}];
g2 = NormalizeGraphics[g1 /. {Polygon[x_] :> GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x],
       RotationTransform[-30 Degree, {0, 0}]], Green -> LightBlue}];
g3 = NormalizeGraphics[g2 /. {Polygon[x_] :> GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x],
       RotationTransform[-30 Degree, {0, 0}]], LightBlue -> Orange}];
g4 = Graphics[First /@ {g1, g2, g3}]
```

[image]

It should look like this

[image]

Fixed with

```
g2 = Normal @ NormalizeGraphics[
    g1 /. {Polygon[x_] :> GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x],
        RotationTransform[-30 Degree, {0, 0}]], Green -> LightBlue}];
```

Comment: Appears related to this question from 10 years ago : [Why doesn't Normal work on GeometricTransformation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11430/363)

Comment: You can use `RotationMatrix` on each point of polygon instead of `GeometricTransformation` with `RotationTransform`. That way you get explicit coordinates after rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems easier to me, if you consider the Graphic primitives directly:

```
poly1 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3]}, {2, 1}, {0, 0}}]

poly2 = TransformedRegion[poly1, RotationTransform[-30 Degree, {0, 0}]] 
poly3 = TransformedRegion[poly2, RotationTransform[-30 Degree, {0, 0}]] 

Graphics[{Green, poly1, Lighter[Blue], poly2, Orange, poly3}]
```

[image]

```
pts1=poly1[[1]]  (*{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3]}, {2, 1}, {0,0}}*)
pts2=poly2[[1]]  (*{{0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {Sqrt[3],1}, {1/2 + Sqrt[3], -1 + Sqrt[3]/2}} *)
pts3=poly3[[1]] (*{{0, 0}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {2,0},
{1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[3]/2) + 1/2 Sqrt[3] (1/2 + Sqrt[3]),1/2 (-(1/2) - Sqrt[3]) + 1/2 Sqrt[3] (-1 + Sqrt[3]/2)}}*)
```

Comment: This still needs `Normal` in my application, but `TransformedRegion` does the job with all built-in functions. E.g. `g2 = Normal[g1 /. {Polygon[x_] :> TransformedRegion[Polygon[x], ...`

Comment: What about `Graphics[{Green, poly1, Orange, poly2}]` ?

Comment: Could do, indeed. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote in the comment - you can use `RotationMatrix` instead.

```
g1 = Graphics[{Green, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, Sqrt[3]}, {2, 1}, {0, 0}}]}];
g2 = g1 /. {Polygon[x_] :> 
     Polygon[RotationMatrix[-30 Degree] . # & /@ x], Green -> Blue};
g3 = g2 /. {Polygon[x_] :> 
     Polygon[RotationMatrix[-30 Degree] . # & /@ x], Blue -> Orange};
g4 = Graphics[First /@ {g1, g2, g3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was useful.